# Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller Boot

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

When I turn on my PC this message comes up:

[image: Boot problem]

What should I do to try to fix this?

Comment: Enter your firmware settings and disable PXE boot.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've bricked your HDD. Maybe you have formatted all of it? Your computer cannot find any disk to boot an operating system from.

Comment: i dual booted my HDD (linux mint and windows 8.1 )

Comment: Looks like you did some kind of mistake while installing OS. Maybe you tried to mix MBR and UEFI type bootloaders and ended up with an unbootable system. For more info you can read ArchLinux's wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows

Comment: Bricked usually mean broken, unrecoverable (e.g. after a failed firmware update).  Gotten it into a non working state is much more likely.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is trying to boot from the network, using PXE.  Unless you explicitly configured a PXE server with the right image this will fail.

When this happens one of the following usually happened:

1. All other boot devices failed (e.g. HDD broke on its own).
2. Or you went to the motherboard firmware (e.g. UEFI or BIOS) and disabled other boot devices.
3. Or you went to the motherboard firmware (e.g. UEFI or BIOS) and set PXE/network boot as first option, with no alternatives.